# Regex - Allow capital letters just at the beginning of words

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, words

I have to check for capital letters to exist just at the beginning of words.

My regex now looks like this:
`/^([A-ZÁÉÚŐÓÜÖÍ]([a-záéúőóüöí]*\s?))+$/`

It's at the words beginning works good, but if the problem not at the beginning of the word it's fails.
For example: `John JohnJ` got validated.

What should i alternate in my regex to works well?

Comment: will there always be a capital letter at the beginning? or will sometimes the input be: sally?

Comment: Yesyes, just and always capital letters at the beginning, any other case should fail at the test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your regex pattern the space is optional, allowing combinations like `JJohn` or `JohnJ` - the key is to make it required between words. There are two ways to do this:

Roll out your pattern:

```
/^[A-ZÁÉÚŐÓÜÖÍ][a-záéúőóüöí]*(?:\s[A-ZÁÉÚŐÓÜÖÍ][a-záéúőóüöí]*)*$/
```

Or make the space in your pattern required, but alternatively allow it to be the end of line (this allows a trailing space though).

```
/^(?:[A-ZÁÉÚŐÓÜÖÍ][a-záéúőóüöí]*(?:\s|$))+$/
```

In both patterns I have removed some superfluous groups of your original and turned all groups into non-capturing ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this: `/^([A-ZÁÉÚŐÓÜÖÍ]{0,1}([a-záéúőóüöí]*\s?))+$/`

With `{a,b}`, `a` is the least amount of characters it will match, whereas `b` is the most amount of characters it will match.

If there is ALWAYS going to be a capital letter at the beginning, instead you can simply use: `/^([A-ZÁÉÚŐÓÜÖÍ]{1}([a-záéúőóüöí]*\s?))+$/`

In this preceding case, `{c}`, `c` is the exact number of characters it will match.

[Here is a resource with good information.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)